# Vue-Cli - Keep class names Webpack UglifyJS

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs, vue-cli-3

After hours of debugging, testing and being completely desperate, I could not find a way to disable class/function names uglifying using UglifyJS for Webpack and Vue-CLI.

I tried this and its combinations:

```js
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                keep_classnames: true,
                keep_fnames: true,
                compress: {
                    keep_classnames: true,
                    keep_fnames: true,
                },
                mangle: {
                    keep_classnames: true,
                    keep_fnames: true,
                },
            },
        }),
    ]
},
```

```js
plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
            keep_classnames: true,
            keep_fnames: true,
            compress: {
                keep_classnames: true,
                keep_fnames: true,
            },
            mangle: {
                keep_classnames: true,
                keep_fnames: true,
            },
        },
    }),
],
```

Nothing seems to work. I just cannot disable class names uglifying.

I need to rely on function and class names, but this way all classes (more precisely Vue component names - I am using class based components) are renamed to `E` as class name.

Could someone help me resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: same problem here and im desperate too

Answer (score 4):

I was able to keep the class names (included Vue.js components) with:

```js
    module.exports = {
      chainWebpack: config => {
        config.optimization
          .minimizer('terser')
          .tap(args => {
            const { terserOptions } = args[0]
            terserOptions.keep_classnames = true
            terserOptions.keep_fnames = true
            return args
          })
       }
    }
```

[credits](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1118#issuecomment-592743751)

Comment: the file this has to be put in is vue.config.js (in case of vue-cli)